# effect of enclosing panelGrid to selectonemenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu, panelgrid

I had a problem with a primefaces selectOneMenu and had it (accidentally) fixed. But I cant figure out why, cause all I have done to get it work is wrapping a panelGrid around all of my components. (I haven't touched the converter or the underlying bean)

Following a example to reproduce the behaviour:

Bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.scope.conversation.ViewAccessScoped;

@Named("testBean")
@ViewAccessScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8394494304848902124L;

    private String selectedString;

    private List<String> things;
    private List<String> listAvailableStrings;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        things = new ArrayList<String>();
        things.add("Car");
        things.add("Cat");
        things.add("House");
        things.add("Bank");

        listAvailableStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        listAvailableStrings.add("one");
        listAvailableStrings.add("two");
        listAvailableStrings.add("three");
        listAvailableStrings.add("four");

    }

    public void printThings() {
        System.out.println(this.things.get(0));
    }

    public void onStringChange() {
        System.out.println(this.selectedString);
    }

    public String getSelectedString() {
        return selectedString;
    }

    public void setSelectedString(String selectedString) {
        this.selectedString = selectedString;
    }

    public List<String> getListAvailableStrings() {
        return listAvailableStrings;
    }

    public void setListAvailableStrings(List<String> listAvailableStrings) {
        this.listAvailableStrings = listAvailableStrings;
    }

    public List<String> getThings() {
        return things;
    }

    public void setThings(List<String> things) {
        this.things = things;
    }

}
```

Version of my xhtml where selectOneMenu is **NOT** working (selectedString is always null):

```
    <h:form id="testForm">
        <p:panelGrid id="testPanel">

            <p:dataTable id="testTable" value="#{testBean.things}" var="thing">
                <p:column headerText="Things">
                    <h:outputText value="#{thing}" />
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

            <p:commandButton id="btnPrintThing" value="DoIT"
                actionListener="#{testBean.printThings()}">
            </p:commandButton>


    </p:panelGrid>
            <p:spacer height="20" width="100%" />

            <p:panelGrid id="panel2" columns="3" border="0" cellpadding="0"
                style="width:80%">

                <p:panelGrid id="panel2_1">

                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel for="somTestSOM" value="selectOneNotWorking"></p:outputLabel>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <h:messages></h:messages>
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="somTestSOM" onchange=""
                                value="#{testBean.selectedString}">
                                <p:ajax update="@([id$=panel2_3])"
                                    listener="#{testBean.onStringChange}" />
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{testBean.listAvailableStrings}"
                                    var="thingSOM" itemValue="#{thingSOM}" itemLabel="#{thingSOM}"></f:selectItems>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:column>

                    </p:row>

                </p:panelGrid>

                <p:spacer width="1" height="250"
                    style="position: relative; bottom: -5px; top: -10px; background-color: #A8A8A8; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px" />


                <p:panelGrid id="panel2_3">
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column colspan="2">
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{testBean.selectedString}"></p:outputLabel>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:panelGrid>

    </h:form>
```

Version of my xhtml where it **IS** working as intended: (selectedString represents the selection of selectOneMenu)

```
<h:form id="testForm">
        <p:panelGrid id="testPanel">

            <p:dataTable id="testTable" value="#{testBean.things}" var="thing">
                <p:column headerText="Things">
                    <h:outputText value="#{thing}" />
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

            <p:commandButton id="btnPrintThing" value="DoIT"
                actionListener="#{testBean.printThings()}">
            </p:commandButton>



            <p:spacer height="20" width="100%" />

            <p:panelGrid id="panel2" columns="3" border="0" cellpadding="0"
                style="width:80%">

                <p:panelGrid id="panel2_1">

                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel for="somTestSOM" value="selectOneNotWorking"></p:outputLabel>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <h:messages></h:messages>
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="somTestSOM" onchange=""
                                value="#{testBean.selectedString}">
                                <p:ajax update="@([id$=panel2_3])"
                                    listener="#{testBean.onStringChange}" />
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{testBean.listAvailableStrings}"
                                    var="thingSOM" itemValue="#{thingSOM}" itemLabel="#{thingSOM}"></f:selectItems>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:column>

                    </p:row>

                </p:panelGrid>

                <p:spacer width="1" height="250"
                    style="position: relative; bottom: -5px; top: -10px; background-color: #A8A8A8; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px" />


                <p:panelGrid id="panel2_3">
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column colspan="2">
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{testBean.selectedString}"></p:outputLabel>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

Used Versions:

- Mojarra 2.2.13
- Primefaces 6.0
- Payara 4.1.1 #163
- CODI 1.0.6
- Weld 2.3.5
- JSF 2.1

Can anyone please explain me why the first version is wrong, so I can take that into account for further developments.

Thank you

Comment: _"Can anyone please explain me why the first version is wrong,"_ That is difficult since it is not a [mcve]. To many 'noise' in the code to be able to even try to reproduce here. And also version info is missing. Please read [ask], [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info to improve your question

Comment: replaced example with a test bean and test xhtmls, where the behaviour can be reproduced. add version info

Comment: _"Mojarra 2.2.13"_ and _"JSF 2.1"_ is contradictory. And is the `p:dataTable` relevant? What if you remove it? The spacers? And did you run your jsf app in dev mode to see if the 'id' that needs to be updated is correct? Did you check the html source if the client side id of the panel2_3 is fundamentally different in both cases (is panelgrid a naming container)

Comment: console during Startup of Glassfish tells me Mojarra 2.2.13, and configured Maven dependency is   <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: the p:dataTable is relevant, as soon as I comment it out, both version do work :-), the id of panel2_3 is identical in both versions